# Spring session bean and RESTEasy + Jackson nullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, jackson, resteasy

I am building a spring based WebApp including a RESTful method call.
I use RESTeasy and jackson to return the username of the current logged in user
(this information is stored in a session bean called "UserBean")

UserBean:

```
@Component("userBean")
@Scope("session")
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private InitApp app;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

OverviewBean is the bean that contains the rest method (including the jackson conversion to json):

```
@Component("overviewBean")
@Scope("view")
@Path("/repairs")
public class OverviewBean {

    @Autowired
    private InitApp app;
    @Autowired
    private UserBean userBean;
    private List<Repair> openRepairsClient;
    private List<Repair> closedRepairsClient;

    @PostConstruct
    public void fillRepairs() {
      try {
        String username = userBean.getUsername();
        openRepairsClient = app.repairService.findOpenRepairsByClient((Client)     app.userService.getUser(userBean.getUsername()));
        closedRepairsClient = app.repairService.findClosedRepairsByClient((Client) app.userService.getUser(userBean.getUsername()));
      } catch (UserServiceException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OverviewBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
   }


    //Getters and setters openRepairsClient/closedRepairsClient

    @GET
    @Path("/getrepairs")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getOpenRepairsInJson() {
        String username = userBean.getUsername();
        return "test";
    }
}
```

fillRepairs() is able to use userBean without any errors. For example the "String username = userBean.getUsername();" within the try catch returns the username correctly.

My issue is that when getOpenRepairsInJson gets called it throws a nullPointerException
on "String username = userBean.getUsername();". It seems that my userBean is not "linked"
at the moment of the method call. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is `OverviewBean` created?

Comment: <mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="be.kdg" /> The beans works normally in my webapp (I edited my post, tempAcceptedBid is now also available and it works just fine)

Comment: I've added more code for clarification